# Использование нескольких DialogFragment

Tags: android, интерфейс, dialogfragment

У меня в программе есть несколько табов, реализованных на фрагментах. На двух из табов, для внесения разных данных, нужны два разных DialogFragmenta. в каждом из диалогов используется интерфейс, с помощью которых я передаю нужные данные в главную активити. Для примера вот один из интерфейсов

```
    public interface MyDialogListener {
    void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialogFragment, int value);
    void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialogFragment);
}
```

а потом из главной активити я передаю данные в другой фрагмент. Просто использую этот интерфейс `implements MyDialogFragment.MyDialogListener` и в методах интерфейса пишу нужный для передачи в другой фрагмент данных.

```
    @Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialogFragment, int value) {
    // Код для передачи данных в другой фрагмент
    TimerFragment timerFragment = (TimerFragment) mAdapter.getItem(1);
    timerFragment.setStartTime(value);
}

@Override
public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialogFragment) {
}
```

То есть каждый таб это фрагмент, на котором можно вызвать DialogFragment и задать какие-то значения в этом табе. Последовательность передачи DialogFragment > MineActivity > OtherFragment. 
  В этом я полностью разобрался. Но возник следующий вопрос. В другом табе (другой фрагмент) нужно ввести иные данные и тот же самый диалог не подойдет. Для этого я создал новый диалог, но как мне передать из него данные во второй фрагмент другого таба? Можно ли как-то использовать один интерфейс на оба диалога? Для одного фрагмента мне нужно только одно числовое значение, а для другого фрагмента кроме этого числа нужно передать еще два строковых значения. Подскажите как это можно реализовать? Я предполагаю что надо вынести интерфейс в отдельный файл, но не знаю как это сделать.
На всякий случай, вот код одного диалога:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

private int mMin;
private int mSec;
private int mValue = mMin + mSec;


public interface MyDialogListener {
    void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialogFragment, int value);
    void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialogFragment);
}

private MyDialogListener mListener;

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Создаем объект класса AlertDialog.Builder и далее с помощью этого объекта строим наше диалоговое окно
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    // Создаем объект абстраткного класса LayoutInflater, чтобы с его помощью передать свой макет в AlertDialog через метод setView()
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_timer, null);

    NumberPicker numberPickerMin = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.numberPickerMin);
    final NumberPicker numberPickerSec = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.numberPickerSec);

    numberPickerMin.setMaxValue(60);
    numberPickerMin.setMinValue(0);
    numberPickerMin.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            mMin = newVal * 60;
        }
    });
    numberPickerSec.setMaxValue(60);
    numberPickerSec.setMinValue(0);
    numberPickerSec.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            mSec = newVal;
        }
    });

    builder.setTitle(R.string.set_time)
            .setView(view)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.set, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(MyDialogFragment.this, mValue);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    mListener.onDialogNegativeClick(MyDialogFragment.this);
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
        mListener = (MyDialogListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement NoticeDialogListener");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Для использования одного интефейса в разных класса необязательно выносить его в отдельный класс. Вы можете использовать его в другом классе так:

   ```
   ClassThatHoldInterfaceDefenition.InterFaceName = ...;
   //в вашем случае
   //MyDialogFragment.MyDialogListener = (MyDialogFragment.MyDialogListener)activity;
   ```
2. Для передачи дополнительных данных можете добавить метод в интерфейс

   ```
   void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialogFragment, int value, String str1, String str2);
   ```

или сделать всего один аргумент `Bundle` и пихать в него всё что хотите в любых количествах и комбинациях.